# Can I set a custom attrubute as a directive to HTML tag like angular‘s directive?

Tags: web-component, directive

I wanner define a directive widthout angular or other framwork,
which like this :

```
<h1 moveable></h1>
```

movableDirective  can make the element h1 do something.

I could define a custom element like a 'movable-h1' extends HTMLHeadingElement,
but without custom element how can i  implement this?  is there something called 'custom-directive' or 'custom-attribute'?

Comment: "*I [want] to define a custom element, ... but without custom element*" Is that your question? In other words you want to make tomato soup without tomatoes?

Comment: No, I want to define a custom attribute on  native element. sorry for my poor engilish.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the web-component tag... I presume you want data-attributes: see the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes. If you want your code to react to data-attribute changes like a directive you have develop that yourself ... or do use W3C standard Web-Components.. they are supported in all major browsers now

Comment: Ok,I will try  Web-Component,  thank you  !